# hashCode implementation strategies

Tags: java, hashcode

Some major JVM classes (such as [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29) or [List implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode%28%29)) implement equals by returning `Σ 31^n * field_n.hashCode()` for every `field_n` that is relevant for the `equals` method. Beside, this approach is recommended by Joshua Bloch in Effective Java (item 9).

However, other classes such as [`Map.Entry` implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#hashCode%28%29) follow different rules. For example, the Map.Entry documentation states that the hash code of a `Map.Entry` should be

```
 (e.getKey()==null   ? 0 : e.getKey().hashCode()) ^
 (e.getValue()==null ? 0 : e.getValue().hashCode())
```

This can sometimes be impractical to use in hash tables, since:

- the hash code of all entries which have the same key and value is 0,
- two entries e1 and e2 so that e1.key = e2.value and e1.value = e2.key have the same hash code.

Why did Java choose this implementation specification for `Map.Entry` hashCode instead of, for example, `31 * (e.getKey()==null   ? 0 : e.getKey().hashCode()) + (e.getValue()==null ? 0 : e.getValue().hashCode())`?

**Edit 1:**

To help figure out the problem, here is an example of useful code where the result has very poor performance due to hash collisions if many entries have the same key and value.

This method computes the frequencies of the entries of different maps (using Guava's Multiset).

```
public static <K, V> Multiset<Map.Entry<K, V>> computeEntryCounts(
        Iterable<Map<K, V>> maps) {
    ImmutableMultiset.Builder<Map.Entry<K, V>> result = ImmutableMultiset.builder();
    for (Map<K, V> map : maps) {
        for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            result.add(entry);
        }
    }
    return result.build();
}
```

Comment: Your implementation doesn't affect the output for key and value being **null**. Also, there are no more than **one** entry with one key in a Map in Java, a key happens only **once** in any Map implementation.

Comment: I know, I was assuming that keys of the HashMap are instances of Map.Entry. This can happen if you want to compute the total count for each key-value entry across several Maps.

Comment: I can't see how this is going to affect this case, unless you want to place all Map.Entry from all maps inside a single map to count them, but this would be clearly wrong.

Comment: While it's true that the `hashCode` definition of `Map.Entry` (and following from this, also the `hashCode` definition of `Map`) is very problematic, it is rather rare to find a `Map` or a `Map.Entry` be used as a key in another `Map` (at least in well-structured code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt there's a good reason — I think it's just an oversight — but it's not a serious problem. It would only come up if you had a `HashSet<Map.Entry<T,T>>` or a `HashMap<Map.Entry<T,T>,V>`, which is not commonly done. (*Edited to add*: Or, as Joachim Sauer points out below, a `HashSet<Map<T,T>>` or a `HashMap<Map<T,T>,V>` — also not commonly done.)

Note that `HashMap<K,V>` does *not* use `Map.Entry<K,V>.hashCode()`, because it looks up entries by their keys *only*, so it just uses `K.hashCode()`.

Comment: Since `Map.hashCode()` is defined in terms of the `hashCode` of its `Map.Entry` elements, this also comes up in a `Map<Map<K,V>,V2>`. Or a `Set<Map<K,V>>`. But those can easily be avoided as well (and usually should be avoided for reasons of readability and design as well).

Comment: All it takes to run into this problem is `someHashSet.addAll(someMap.entrySet())` or something like this [Guava issue](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=458). All entries like "a"=>"a" are guaranteed to collide and the performance is guaranteed to be terrible (or at least less then optimal since JDK 8). You rarely run into it, but when you do it's pretty bad.

Answer (score 0):

My personal guess is, hashCode should be fast too.

Since you are allowed to override hashCode there is no problem with it.
Change it when you know a better fitting algorithm for your case

Comment: Sorry, but this is not right. `Map.Entry` is an *interface*. It's not describing a *default* algorithm that *it* implements but that subclasses can override; rather, it's prescribing a specific algorithm that implementers are required to implement.

Comment: When sun/oracle needs in all cases a certain implementation, than they MUST use an abstract class instead of an interface.